# Интерфейс для Nagios/Naemon

Tags: javascript, php

Зашла задача мне с напарником: создать свой интерфейс для системы Naemon или Nagios. Языки: php и js. Фреймворки: laravel + vuejs.
Гуглил я очень много, и в принципе вроде бы как нашёл ответы и варианты того, как можно это сделать. Но все равно до конца не понятно как подобраться к данным, которые выдаёт нагиос. Думал взять графану и переделать ее визуализацию, но не уверен что можно ее менять там. В идеале, написать свой интерфейс, никак не связанный с другими платформами по типу графаны. Вопроса по сути 2:

1. Реально ли в 2 человека написать свою морду для nagios?
2. Есть ли какие-то инструменты, которые можно переоформить, дописать, переделать под свой дизайн?

Comment: а вы пробовали погуглить nagios web interface, nagios ui или nagios gui?

Comment: Ну конечно, я обрыл весь интернет. Мне не нужны готовые решения, я хочу написать свой интерфейс. Но не могу до конца понять как это сделать

Comment: Ну конечно, я обрыл весь интернет. Мне не нужны готовые решения, я хочу написать свой интерфейс. Но не могу до конца понять как это сделать. В виде плагина, или еще каким-то образом

Comment: Так вы спрашиваете вариант 2 - дописать, доделать и тд. Можно взять готовый интерфейс и переделать его.

Comment: Хорошо, кто-нибудь, может мне на одном из примеров (Icinga, NagiosXI, Кокпит) показать или рассказать как происходит вывод данных на фронт? Я имею в виду, каким образом морда цепляется за данные, как она это делает? 

По идее, из того что я искал, все упирается в базу данных. Я не могу понять как записывается и как берется инфа из базы данных, чтобы вывести на фронт. Как это в самом голом нагиосе я понял, но я не могу понять как это сделано в тех проектах, где есть своя веб морда. Вот это ключевая и самая главная проблема, и она же последняя, которую нужно решить.